# php date and time regex

Tags: php, regex

This is the user input:

```
Date: DD-MM-YYYY
Time: HH:SS
```

Can anyone help me creating the pattern for these regular expressions.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ those are very trivial, its better for you to understand how regular expressions work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some nice examples on the PHP manual for date validation.

Try the `Checkdate()` function [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
/Date: (\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}).*?Time: (\d{2}:\d{2})/
```